# Comparing strings in two columns of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data -

```
Code1   Code2
G01621  E04621
```

I want to show all codes that are in code1 but not in code2.

I wrote the following SQL, but it is returning incorrect data -

```
select * from codes c1
left join codes c2 
on lower(c1.code1) = lower(c2.code2)
where c2.code2 is null
```

Comment: How are the results incorrect?

Comment: Please expand your meaning for "in code1 but not in code2". Provide additional data as a sample set of 1 is not very useful. Data should include data rows that should be selected and some that should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select c.code1
from codes c
where not exists (select 1
                  from codes c2
                  where lower(c2.code2) = lower(c.code1)
                 );
```

Comment: This is returning some records that exist in both. I have even added a `tolower` before comparing the two values.

Comment: No, there must be some difference between the codes.  It's most likely white space or unprintable characters.

Answer (score 0):

use `trim()` function

```
select * from codes c1
left join codes c2 
on trim(lower(c1.code1)) = trim(lower(c2.code2))
where c2.code1 is null;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c6d3ada551c5e973da2e0f7dc77ed596)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use `except` :

```
select c1.code1 from codes c1
except
select c2.code2 from codes c2
```